# Cannot open text files with Turkish characters

Tags: windows-7, unicode, character-encoding

I am learning Turkish and I would like to be able to open Turkish text files. I am running Windows 7 and I have even installed the Turkish display language for Windows.

But I am still not able to open and see text-files in Turkish correctly.
VLC also has problems processing the subtitle files. Turkish people can see the files perfectly fine however.

[image: Turkish characters misformed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is apparently data in ISO-8859-9 (or windows-1254) misinterpreted as ISO-8859-1 (or windows-1252). You need a program where the character encoding can be set manually, or you need to convert the data to another format, preferably UTF-8.

Changing the system language via Control Panel is another option, as it will set the default 8-bit encoding. But it has a much wider impact than you expect, so I would not recommend it.

Comment: Actually this was the only option to make these subtitles work, but it makes installers and other software programs think I am Turkish, so their default language is Turkish.